# Not able to hold items

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i have this Item class

```
public class Item {

    private String id; 
    private int count;
    private String  name;


    public int getcount() {
        return this.count; 
    }

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        this.id = "";
    }

    public Item(String id, String name) {
        this.name=name;
        this.id=id;
    }

    public Item(int count) {
        this.count=count;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getItemId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

then i have ItemSet class which will contain List of items

```
public  class ItemSet  extends ArrayList<Item> {

    private List<Item> hold;

    ItemSet(Item item) {
        this.hold.add(item);
    }

    ItemSet() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    public List<Item> getItemSet() {
        return this.hold;
    }
}
```

I have transaction classs which will contain List of ItemSets:

```
public class Transaction extends ArrayList<ItemSet> {

    // ArrayList<String> l;
    public ItemSet getUniqueItem() {
        ResultSet rs;
        Database d=new Database();
        ItemSet unique=new ItemSet();
        unique.clear();
        String query="Select id,name from item";
        rs=d.sendQuery(query);
        try{  
            while(rs.next()) {
                //System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"\t"+rs.getString(2));
                Item item=new Item(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2));
                unique.add(item);        
            } 
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }

        for(Item item:unique) {
            // System.out.println(item.getItemId()+": "+item.getItemName());
        }
        return unique;
    }

    public int countItems(ItemSet itemset) {
        ResultSet rs;
        Database d=new Database();
        String query="";
        int count=0;
        for(Item i:itemset) {
            String id=i.getItemId();
            query="SELECT count(*) FROM `item_transaction` where item_id="+i;
            rs=d.sendQuery(query);
            try {
                while(rs.next()) {
                    //System.out.print(rs.getString(1));
                    count=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
                    System.out.print(count+"\t");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){ }
        }

        return count;
    }

}
```

And this is main classs

```
public class Ap {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Transaction t=new Transaction();
        Transaction Ci=new Transaction();
        Transaction Li=new Transaction();

        ItemSet I=t.getUniqueItem();
        for(Item i:I) {
            System.out.println(i);
            ItemSet itemSet=new ItemSet(i);
            Ci.add(itemSet);
        }

        for(ItemSet itemSet:Ci) {
            int x=t.countItems(itemSet);
            System.out.print(x+"\t");
        }

        /* Iterator iter=Li.iterator();
           while(iter.hasNext()) {
               // System.out.print(iter.next()+"\t");
           }
        */

    }
}
```

Problem is that am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ItemSet.<init>(ItemSet.java:25)
at Ap.main(Ap.java:30)
```

Where

`ItemSet.java:25` refers to `this.hold.add(item);`

and where

`Ap.java:30` refers to `ItemSet itemSet=new ItemSet(i);  // creating new ItemSet`

Please help me find my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

```
this.hold.add(item);
```

`hold (List)` is by defaul `null` because instance variable. You need to instantiate before adding  item. What ever operations you perform on `null` results `NullPointerException`

Example:

```
ItemSet(Item item)
{
   hold = new ArrayList<Item>();
   this.hold.add(item);

}
```

Any specific reason to extend `ArrayList()?`

Comment: So that i can hold List of items. Am i wrong in using ArrayList??

Comment: You don't need to extend ArrayList to hold items. You can just instantiate like above example. You should extends a class if you want to overrided functionality (or) use super class attribute. But, in this case you are not doing either. So, don't need to extend.

Comment: ok thanks for the info. did as you said. But now am not able to iterate ItemSet I which contains Items

  ItemSet I=t.getUniqueItem();

how to go about it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private List<Item> hold = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

inside the `ItemList` class.

What you have written so far is just a private field definition - you did not instantiate the `hold` object (i.e. you did not create a list) so `hold` is null, thus the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

You have **not initialized** the `hold List`, before using it...

Use the below code in `ItemSet` to initialize the `hold`.

`private List<Item> hold = new ArrayList<Item>();`

Comment: NOT related to your answer. Why not edit existing answer? I am seeing one deleted and one active answer. Just want to make sure it is not a bug in system.